# Targeting elements with-in an Array using JQuery (Syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array, of which I wish to target specific elements using `$(".someArray")[i]`, for i=0,1,2,..

I wish to target elements in this fashion:  `$(".someArray[3] > #someElement")`;

How can I do this? What's the correct syntax, I can't find it!

Answer (score 1):

[`$.fn.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) can be used

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$(".someArray").eq(3).children("#someElement")
```

Note: that the supplied index is zero-based, and refers to the position of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree.

As per comment, you need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(".someArray").eq(3).find("fieldset.someElement")
```

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - It's not working however. Consider the expression: #new > div > div.someArray.active > div > div > fieldset.someElement.  In the console, $(".someArray") returns three objects, but using the exression above I can target the first object only..

Comment: @Rich, If you want to find the desecendents use  `$(".someArray").eq(3).find("fieldset.someElement")`